# Use gstreamer to take rtsp input and output rtmp

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, rtmp, aac

I'm trying to use gstreamer to go from h264 rtsp input to rtmp output to youtube without re-encoding. in ffmpeg I can simply do a codec copy, but in gstreamer, I can't my pipeline to work:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://rtsp/input" protocols=tcp latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! flvmux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location='rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key live=true'`

I have a feeling it has to do with the audio. I'm receiving aac audio from the rtsp feed but can't figure out how to parse it into the rtmp output.

Comment: I was able to get it working with this: 

`gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://rstp/input" protocols=tcp latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location='rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key live=true' audiotestsrc is-live=true ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! voaacenc bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4 ! mux.`

But this is just creating a blank audio track, how can I codec copy the aac audio?